# Shouldn't the person who rolled back the author's improvements to their own answer provide an alternative answer instead?

Tags: discussion, edits, answers

https://stackoverflow.com/a/33155052/1011527

The original author of the answer edited their answer with an improvement.  Someone else rolled it back to the original answer, instead of providing their own separate answer.  Isn't this a classic case of an edit that "disagrees with the poster's intention"?

Comment: He didn't really edit but rolled it back to the author's original. It looks like the author added some error checking and common sense didn't like that.  No reason for another answer, from what I see, but not sure why the rollback either. Roll it back again and, if it happens again, flag for a mod so you don't get into an edit war.

Comment: Thanks @codeMagic, I performed the rollback.

Comment: Looks just like his recent dislike of try/catch. The rollback to version 2 is definitely the best option (as that contains more alternatives for future users).

Comment: YSC has rolled back again. I have flagged for moderator attention @codeMagic

Comment: Ha, I just saw that. That's all there is to be done. Let a mod lock it from editing most likely or whatever they want to do.

Comment: YCS is a smart guy, probably 10x smarter than I am. If he would just comment what he is doing, he might shed some of that brilliance around a bit

Comment: Two rollbacks sequentially raises an auto-flag. Leave it at that.

Comment: @TinyGiant I didn't realize that. Good to know

Comment: I didn't realize that either @TinyGiant

Comment: @JayBlanchard I've changed your wording because when I came to your question, it looked to me like it was a classical case of someone swooping in with a substantial code change out of the blue. The fact that YCS is reverting the author's own improvements to the answer is highly peculiar, and most likely unjustified.

Comment: Thanks @Louis. I should have been more thorough in making the edits earl...... *giraffe*!

Comment: @YourCommonSense I'm reasonably sure that your edit conflicts with the author's intent, and sure enough to roll it back for now. If the OP contradicts me and actually agrees with your edit suggestion, let him be the one to roll back my rollback, okay?

Comment: Interesting. mysqli_connect can throw exceptions apparently, but it is not documented for some reason.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Edits should preserve the intent of the original answer. Unilaterally altering the code of the answerer in this fashion is not an acceptable edit, so I've rolled it back.

I await [another lengthy complaint about my actions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307167/my-edit-to-make-a-code-dump-question-into-an-mcve-was-rolled-back-but-the-questi).

Comment: And YCS strikes again! I'm slightly baffled.

Comment: Maybe want to lock that post or something like this:http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33155052/revisions ?!

Comment: Wow, now he rolled back *your* rollback! He's clearly cruising for a food fight.

Comment: Someone's running around in the PHP tag like it's their own private fiefdom, but it's not you, Brad. So what's the final tally on this? We've seen at least three meta posts, one ragequit (or not... he seems to be back), too many questionable and abusive comments to count, meta-vigilantism... What other things could have been done with all the ♦ time wasted on this?

Answer (score 10):

Altering the code of an answerer because you disagree with their coding style or used methods is completly unnaceptable.

Answer (score -10):

Editing other writers without permission, **even if the original text is wrong**, **is impolite and rude** if not ill-mannered.  There are different ways to solve such problems.

However, this behavior is, to some extent, allowed in Stack Overflow (and Wikipedia) and it's prone to abuse. I doubt that it will change even when it affects the final product (question and answer).

Comment: So under what circumstances do you think editing is acceptable, given that there is no mechanism on SO to ask for permission?

Comment: Editing someone's text is not impolite and rude. Putting your text up for everyone to read while it's full of errors, is. By posting your contribution to the sites you mention, you agree to the fact that your text can be edited.

Answer (score -34):

I am not too good with SO rules, so, here goes just my unauthorized opinion.

I wouldn't say that the post was edited by the author's intent. Instead, the edit was rather urged by a comment from someone else. While the author confirmed that they have no idea if another solution ever works.

So, I rather agree with the *author's* intention, which I decided to support.

And, to my common sense, I see no point in writing another answer if there is already a correct one. While it is someone who disagrees, should have expressed their opinion in their own answer.

---

Update.
It just occurred to me, that some people may take this answer as an explanation, why I rolled back the particular post. But it was not. It was just an attempt to clarify "intentions" that were discussed.

As of the rollback itself, it has nothing to do with these matters. The reason was plain technical: to make the answer technically correct back.

Also, neither it was a problem with understanding of the original post. This is the problem with understanding particular technology only.

Comment: If you claim that a comment motivated your rollback of the original author's answer, it may (or may not) help support your claim if you pointed out what that comment was.

Comment: "While the author confirmed that they have no idea if another solution ever works." -- That's just not true. The relevant sentence in the comment is "Ah I wasn't aware that warnings would actually be properly catchable." Note the past tense. I see no reason to think that CollinD didn't try it before editing the answer.

Comment: My intention was really to provide as complete of a list of solutions as possible. Adding the `try/catch` option to the list was certainly spurred on by a comment, but that really just led me to doing a bit more research. I can certainly appreciate your position to keep the answer more reflective of my original understanding, (hence my not even initiating a rollback of my own). That said, I don't think it harms anything (and truly does offer an improvement) to simply add additional information as an answerer is made aware of it in the spirit of a more complete/robust solution.

Comment: You rolled back *what the original author wrote*.  When the original author expressed surprise and wonder at "why was my post rolled back", and someone fixed it, you repeated it.  You then engaged in a repeated edit war, rolling back every rollback that undid your rollback.  You never asked the original poster to clarify.  Unless you believe you are somehow better able to understand the original poster's, I think this isn't why you acted the way you did.